# MongoDB 3.2 - creating a CRUD admin for a certain database

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a CRUD database administrator.
From what I read from official documentation, there is a role **readWrite**, but I don't really got the process of creating an admin.

So I ran `mongod` without `--auth` and created a user with these parameters:

`use myCustomDB`

`db.createUser({
     user: "snoop",
     pwd:"stickyickyicky",
     roles:[{role:"readWrite", db:"myCustomDB"}]
});`

The command line answered **Successfully added new user blah blah..**

but when I authenticate it returns **1**, which, I suppose is **true**. But when I run command for example `db.peops.find()` it gives me this `Error: error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on myCustomDB.peops", "co de" : 13 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be your find call. Try formatting like this:

```
 db.getCollection('peops').find({})
```

If that's not it, it might be your auth schema. This may not be the best method, but I thought I would share the steps I take to setup a super admin and database specific admin, and a read only user. The all caps should be replaced with corresponding credential / db name:

1.Change Mongo Security Method

```
            sudo service mongod start
            mongo
            use admin
            db.system.version.remove({})
            db.system.version.insert({ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 })
```

2.Create Super Admin User

```
            use admin
            db.createUser( { user: "SUPERADMINUSER", pwd: "SUPERADMINPASS", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] } )
```

3.Create db Admin with read/write access

```
            use DATABASE
            db.createUser( { user: "DBADMIN", pwd: "DBPASSWORD", roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "DATABASE" }, { role: "readWrite", db: "DATABASE" }] } )
            db.createUser( { user: "DBREADONLYUSER", pwd: "DBREADONLYPASS", roles: [ { role: "read", db: "DATABASE" }] } )
```

4.Edit mongod.config in /etc folder

```
            sudo service mongod stop
            in mongod.config edit so that auth = true is not commented out.
```

5. Restart mongo, security in place

```
            sudo service mongod start
```

***Troubleshooting: If you are running mongo 3.2 you can likely skip the db.system.version remove and insert commands, you may want/need to upgrade to SCRAM-SHA-1, if so run db.adminCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1}); set up users the same way as shown above, when editing your /etc/mongod.conf file instead of auth=true comment in security: and add authorization=true as follows:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```